# Cakephp, what is it good for?

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks, content-management-system

I hear a lot about cakephp, it's even a requirement for some hiring companies on job boards. I'm a beginner programming but I like making things from scratch because I understand everything and it feel more flexible.

For my next project I want to build a site which has users, users can vote and they can post entries as well as manage their entries. Would cakephp be a good framework for this or should I just do it on my own?

Comment: "I'm a beginner programmer... I like making things from scratch" that's *exactly* what separates you from the senior programmers. The sooner you get past that hump the better you'll do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm a great fan of CakePHP and, up until recently, I've used it for all of the projects I've worked on over the last four years, introducing it to two companies along the way. Now I'm working in Coldfusion so I don't use it at work, but I still do at home.

If you're just starting out then you don't need to worry about CakePHP as a job requisite just yet! Learn PHP as well as you can - get your hands dirty and do all the repetitive stuff like connecting to databases and building queries.

More important in a job application (and when developing using CakePHP or any framework) is to have a good knowledge of the underlying language, in this case PHP. Once you know it well you can make an informed decision about frameworks and MVC. Then you'll *really* see the advantages, whether it's Cake, Codeigniter or something built by the girl nextdoor.

Answer (score 5):

CakePHP is an MVC framework that was built using the Ruby on Rails style of architecture. More than anything it gives you a convention that you can follow, and other developers can follow, that is well documented. If you build it yourself from scratch you may learn more about the underlying PHP APIs, but you'll lose out on the benefits (likely) of a commonly accepted design architecture.

I would suggest learning CakePHP or try out CodeIgniter instead. The idea is that you can quickly roll out an application with a very robust feature set, that is well tested, that doesn't require you to spend months building out the core components. It is more important that you are capable and efficient then specifically that you know one framework over the other.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm excited about Cakephp now :-)

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP is a web framework for PHP implementing the Model-View-Controller (MVC) paradigm. It's designed to make PHP web development easier, but the overall workflow is completely different to that of plain PHP.

No-one here can tell you what works best for you, but I'd suggest learning to use PHP before learning to use CakePHP (just as the Ruby on Rails guide suggests learning Ruby before Rails). You won't need to, but it will help a lot.

Model-View-Controller (MVC) frameworks for other languages that you may be aware of and/or familiar with include Django for Python, Ruby on Rails for Ruby, and ASP.NET MVC for ASP.NET.

Comment: ahh model-view-controller sounds too foreign for me. I think I'll stick with plain php.

Comment: If MVC sounds too foreign to you then you absolutely have to learn CakePHP. It is the most popular architecture currently on the market for building out web based applications. It would help your career to know and understand it.

Comment: As someone who's been developing Cake application back from its birth, I'd advice against learning (only) it today. It's a dead end stuck with having to support PHP4, along many other reasons (some community related). The original Cake developers spun off the [Lithium](http://lithify.me/) framework. You can also look at the new comer [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and maybe even Zend Framework which is PHP5. It's OK if you have a job that requires it but don't limit your learning to just CakePHP because many better frameworks have emerged since then.

Comment: @kizzx2 thanks for sharing a negative side! I did not know that. Are other frameworks as easy? BTW I think cakephp supports php5 as well

Comment: The current version of CakePHP (1.3) supports both PHP4 and PHP5. CakePHP 2.0 is under development and will support only PHP5.

Comment: "stuck with having to support PHP4" In the old days we called that backwards compatibility. You still code for IE6 don't you? Well the final release of that is over nine years old.

Comment: @Leo Backwards compatibility is good and well, but a project also has to look forward. And that's what I'm missing with CakePHP. While other frameworks work on bringing their frameworks to PHP 5.3, the CakePHP devs work on bringing the framework to PHP 5.2, a PHP version which recently was announced as no longer supported...

Comment: @Daniel Agreed, but CakePHP can pride itself on putting stability before bleeding edge. I'm not really missing anything from 5.2 or 5.3, but my brain upgrades slower than Cake.